# Remove specific item in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove some specific '' in the list using python.

The list is [1,'','',2,'','','',3,'']. I want to remove just one '' between two values. which means the output I want is [1,'',2,'','',3]. The code I had shows as below:

```
for j in range (len(lst)):
    if len(lst[j]) == 1:
        lst.remove(lst[j+1])
```

Comment: I suggest that you build a new list rather than modifying the list that you iterate over.

Comment: This is a sample. The actual list is too big to manually build

Comment: Is your question how to remove multiple blank strings from this list?

Comment: yes. I should be clear sorry.

Comment: Do you want to remove consecutive blanks or do you want to have one blank between each pair?

Comment: I want to remove one blank between each pair

Comment: @andy The problem is that when you remove an element, the index on the next iteration is incorrect. If you really want to modify the existing list, you will need to take this into account and use a `while` loop instead of a `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [1,'','',2,'','','',3,'']

new_list = []
for v, g in groupby(l):
    new_list += list(g) if v != '' else list(g)[:-1]

print(new_list)
```

Prints:

```
[1, '', 2, '', '', 3]
```

Version 2 (one-liner with `itertools.chain`):

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

l = [1,'','',2,'','','',3,'']
new_list = [*chain.from_iterable(list(g) if v != '' else list(g)[:-1] for v, g in groupby(l))]
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `del` operator. Just provide the index. `del lst[1]`.

Comment: This will still run into problems with the index during iteration.

Comment: yes. But it worked even with the index error! Why?